# non meaningful operation for fractor error when storing new value in data frame: R

Tags: r

I am trying to update a a value in a data frame but am getting--what seems to me--a weird error about operation that I don't think I am using.

Here's a summary of the data:

```
> str(us.cty2015@data)
'data.frame':   3108 obs. of  15 variables:
$ STATEFP   : Factor w/ 52 levels "01","02","04",..: 17 25 33 46 4 14 16 24 36 42 ...
$ COUNTYFP  : Factor w/ 325 levels "001","003","005",..: 112 91 67 9 43 81 7 103 72 49 ...
$ COUNTYNS  : Factor w/ 3220 levels "00023901","00025441",..: 867 1253 1600 2465 38 577 690 1179 1821 2104 ...
$ AFFGEOID  : Factor w/ 3220 levels "0500000US01001",..: 976 1472 1879 2813 144 657 795 1395 2098 2398 ...
$ GEOID     : Factor w/ 3220 levels "01001","01003",..: 976 1472 1879 2813 144 657 795 1395 2098 2398 ...
$ NAME      : Factor w/ 1910 levels "Abbeville","Acadia",..: 1558 1703 1621 688 856 1075 148 1807 1132 868 ...
$ LSAD      : Factor w/ 9 levels "00","03","04",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ ALAND     : num  1.66e+09 1.10e+09 3.60e+09 2.12e+08 1.50e+09 ...
$ AWATER    : num  2.78e+06 5.24e+07 3.50e+07 2.92e+08 8.91e+06 ...
$ t_pop     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n_wht     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n_free_blk: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n_slv     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n_blk     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n_free    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> str(us.cty1860@data)
'data.frame':   2126 obs. of  29 variables:
$ DECADE       : Factor w/ 1 level "1860": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ NHGISNAM     : Factor w/ 1236 levels "Abbeville","Accomack",..: 1142 1218 1130 441 812 548 1144 56 50 887 ...
$ NHGISST      : Factor w/ 41 levels "010","050","060",..: 32 13 9 36 16 36 16 30 23 39 ...
$ NHGISCTY     : Factor w/ 320 levels "0000","0010",..: 142 206 251 187 85 231 131 12 6 161 ...
$ ICPSRST      : Factor w/ 37 levels "1","11","12",..: 5 13 21 26 22 26 22 10 15 17 ...
$ ICPSRCTY     : Factor w/ 273 levels "10","1010","1015",..: 25 93 146 72 247 122 12 10 228 45 ...
$ ICPSRNAM     : Factor w/ 1200 levels "ABBEVILLE","ACCOMACK",..: 1108 1184 1097 432 791 535 1110 55 49 860 ...
$ STATENAM     : Factor w/ 41 levels "Alabama","Arkansas",..: 32 13 9 36 16 36 16 30 23 39 ...
$ ICPSRSTI     : int  14 31 44 49 45 49 45 24 34 40 ...
$ ICPSRCTYI    : int  1210 1970 2910 1810 710 2450 1130 110 50 1450 ...
$ ICPSRFIP     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ STATE        : Factor w/ 41 levels "010","050","060",..: 32 13 9 36 16 36 16 30 23 39 ...
$ COUNTY       : Factor w/ 320 levels "0000","0010",..: 142 206 251 187 85 231 131 12 6 161 ...
$ PID          : num  1538 735 306 1698 335 ...
$ X_CENTROID   : num  1348469 184343 1086494 -62424 585888 ...
$ Y_CENTROID   : num  556680 588278 -229809 -433290 -816852 ...
$ GISJOIN      : Factor w/ 2126 levels "G0100010","G0100030",..: 1585 627 319 1769 805 1788 823 1425 1079 2006 ...
$ GISJOIN2     : Factor w/ 2126 levels "0100010","0100030",..: 1585 627 319 1769 805 1788 823 1425 1079 2006 ...
$ SHAPE_AREA   : num  2.35e+09 1.51e+09 8.52e+08 2.54e+09 6.26e+08 ...
$ SHAPE_LEN    : num  235777 155261 166065 242608 260615 ...
$ t_pop        : int  25043 653 4413 8184 174491 1995 4324 17187 4649 8392 ...
$ n_wht        : int  24974 653 4295 6892 149063 1684 3001 17123 4578 2580 ...
$ n_free_blk   : int  69 0 2 0 10939 2 7 64 12 409 ...
$ n_slv        : int  0 0 116 1292 14484 309 1316 0 59 5403 ...
$ n_blk        : int  69 0 118 1292 25423 311 1323 64 71 5812 ...
$ n_free       : num  25043 653 4297 6892 160007 ...
$ frac_free    : num  1 1 0.974 0.842 0.917 ...
$ frac_free_blk: num  1 NA 0.0169 0 0.4303 ...
$ frac_slv     : num  0 0 0.0263 0.1579 0.083 ...

> str(overlap)
'data.frame':   15266 obs. of  7 variables:
$ cty2015         : Factor w/ 3108 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1082 1082 1082 ...
$ cty1860         : Factor w/ 2126 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 1047 1012 1296 1963 2033 2058 2065 736 1413 1569 ...
$ area_inter      : num  1.66e+09 2.32e+05 9.81e+04 1.07e+09 7.67e+07 ...
$ area1860        : num  1.64e+11 1.81e+11 1.54e+09 2.91e+09 2.32e+09 ...
$ frac_1860       : num  1.01e-02 1.28e-06 6.35e-05 3.67e-01 3.30e-02 ...
$ sum_frac_1860   : num  1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ scaled_frac_1860: num  1.01e-02 1.28e-06 6.35e-05 3.67e-01 3.30e-02 ...
```

I am trying to multiply a vector of variables `vars <- c("t_pop", "n_wht", "n_free_blk", "n_slv", "n_blk", "n_free")` in the `us.cty1860@data` data frame by a scalar `overlap$scaled_frac_1860[i]`, then add it to the same vector of variables in the `us.cty2015@data` data frame, and finally overwrite the variables in the `us.cty2015@data` data frame.

When I make the following call, I get an error that seems to be saying that I am trying to preform invalid operations on factors (which is not the case (you can confirm from the `str` output)).

```
> us.cty2015@data[overlap$cty2015[1], vars] <- us.cty2015@data[overlap$cty2015[1], vars] + (overlap$scaled_frac_1860[1] * us.cty1860@data[overlap$cty1860[1], vars])
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

However, when I don't attempt to overwrite the old value, the operation works fine.

```
> us.cty2015@data[overlap$cty2015[1], vars] + (overlap$scaled_frac_1860[1] * us.cty1860@data[overlap$cty1860[1], vars])         
  t_pop    n_wht n_free_blk    n_slv    n_blk   n_free
0 118.3889 113.6468  0.1317233 4.610316 4.742039 113.7785
```

I'm sure there are better ways of accomplishing what I am trying to do but does anyone have any idea what is going on?

### Edit:

I am using the following libraries: `rgdal`, `rgeos`, and `maptools`

The all the data/object are coming from [NHGIS shapefiles](http://www.nhgis.org/documentation/gis-data#tiger-doc) 1860 and 2015 United States Counties.

Comment: The error message says `Summary.factor` was called and that the `max` function and ">=" operator were unhappy with the class of objects offered. Clearly the expression you produced has neither of those functions, so I surmise that you are using a package that has redefined some of the basic R operators. And you are not telling us what package created these objects, so there not much point in saying anything more until you produce a complete example.

Comment: Also have conscerns about this construct: `us.cty2015@data[overlap$cty2015[1], vars] <-` It would imply that there was an assignment function that handles both S3 and S4 decoding. Maybe that exists but seems possibly too optimistic.

Comment: @42- I included an edit listing the libraries I am using and also a link to some documentation on the origin of the objects. I'm sorry I can't say much more than that.

Comment: I know it doesn't really help because something is obviously different but I have preformed nearly identical lines of code before, using the exact same objects and libraries, without issue.